# Receive byte array from server to client? BinaryReader / BinaryWriter error?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, binaryreader, binarywriter

Hi i'm a newbie in c# and doing server and client for sharing text file via tcp/ip socket connection. I used the BinaryReader / BinaryWriter to upload from client to server but stucking from server to client:
From client to server:

```
Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(fileName);
                writer.Write(authorName);
                writer.Write(fileContent);
                var data = stream.ToArray();  // send this data array to server
                clientSock.Connect("192.168.7.48", 9050); // targets machine ip add and port num
                clientSock.Send(data);
                writer.Dispose();
                stream.Dispose();
                clientSock.Close();
```

In server:

public void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

```
    String content = String.Empty;
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;
    bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error asshole-0");
   if (bytesRead > 0)
   {
       if (flag == 0)
       {
           var stream = new MemoryStream(state.buffer);
           var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
           fileName = reader.ReadString();
           authorName = reader.ReadString();
           fileContent = reader.ReadString();
           reader.Dispose();
           stream.Dispose();
           flag++;
           Console.Write(fileName + authorName);
           Console.Write(fileContent);
       }
       string path = @"C:\"+fileName;

       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
       sw.Write(fileContent);
       sw.Close();
       sw.Dispose();
       SqlCmd();
   }
   else
   {
       Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWrite));
   }

}
```

stream.Dispose();

Now i try to use the same way from server to client but got error

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(state.buffer);
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

stateObject is error?

Comment: Please some more specific error information, e.g. the exception thrown with a stack trace.

Comment: Provide the network code otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: `BinaryReader.ReadString()` expects the whole string to be present in the buffer, prepended by its length. `ReadInt32()` expects four bytes to be present. A `Socket.Receive()` can receive a partial message, so either not the whole string can't be read or the int lacks one or more bytes. You'll have to buffer all input (i.e. store data between `Receive()` calls) until you start processing it.

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEM**:It may be that the whole data can't be read at once because socket receive data in buffers.
**SOLUTION**:have you think about what is the use of byteread when `handler.EndReceive(ar)`is called.It tells you about the data read yet means you have to check whether you have received the whole data and if yes then continue to convert it to string.

```
    Public Class State
    Public CLient As Net.Sockets.Socket
    Public Const BufferConst As Integer = 100
    Public TmpBuffer(BufferConst) As Byte
    Public sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
End Class

Public Sub SendText(txt As String, socket As Net.Sockets.Socket)
    socket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(txt + "•"))
End Sub

Public Sub ReadData(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim state As State = ar.AsyncState
    Try
        Dim read As Integer = state.CLient.EndReceive(ar)
        If read > 0 Then
            state.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetChars(state.TmpBuffer))
            If state.sb.ToString.IndexOf("•") > 0 Then
                'All data have been recived
                Console.WriteLine(state.sb.ToString())
            Else
                ' Not Complete Start it again
                state.CLient.BeginReceive(state.TmpBuffer, 0, state.BufferConst, Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadData), state)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write("Read Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember and `Flush` the streams after you write them. From the snippets you have shared so far it doesn't look like there's a flush.

Have a look at the [Stream Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) docs